Macro to trigger building block for specific text in ms word docs
I am looking for a macro which run and trigger the building block for a specific text in ms word docs.
i love this below code got from this forum.
But my thing is how to find a particular text and trigger this macro automatically
For example: If my word docs having text "MyBB" then i need the building block named "MyBB" comes automatically once i run the code
i have stored many building blocks and activating it with F3 key on particular text in daily work
Need a help to modify the code which runs a mentioned above
Sub InsertMyBB()
'
' Assumes that the Building Block is of the type AutoText (wdTypeAutoText) in Category "General"
' See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243303(v=office.12).aspx
'
' This is based in part upon contributions from Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman - any errors remain mine
' Written by Charles Kenyon February 2016
'
Dim sBBName As String
Dim sTempName As String
Dim oBB As BuildingBlock
sBBName = "MyBB" 'use the name of your building block instead of "MyBB"
sTempName = ThisDocument.FullName ' puts name and full path of template in string variable
On Error Resume Next
Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks  ' thank you Timothy Rylatt
Set oBB = Application.Templates(sTempName).BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeAutoText) \_
.Categories("General").BuildingBlocks(sBBName)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
oBB.Insert Selection.Range, True
Else
MsgBox Prompt:="The Building Block '" & sBBName & "' cannot be found in " & \_
ThisDocument.Name & ".", Title:="Didn't Work!"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub INSERTTABLE()
Dim strSearch As String


    strSearch = "3000"
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .Format = True
        .Text = strSearch
        .Execute
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And icount < 1000
    icount = icount + 1
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
       Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Range.InsertAutoText
     
     Loop
   
    strSearch = "5000"
      Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
         .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .Format = True
        .Text = strSearch
        .Execute
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And icount < 1000
    icount = icount + 1
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory

    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Range.InsertAutoText

    Loop
   
    End With
    End With
   End Sub


Are you asking how to search a document for all instances of "MyBB" and replace that text with what's in the building block?  Or are you asking for a more general approach where the code is looking for all instances of text which matches the name of any building block?

Hi there. Please edit your post and provide debugging details, explaining at what point in your attempt to resolve the problem you aren't getting the result you expect from your code.  We don't do the coding for you -- we help you resolve problems or errors in your own code.

Yes. Find all instances of "MyBB" in word document and it should be changed to table/building block.  I saved the building block as "MyBB"

But code should look only for "MyBB" ?

Yes.  My thought is if one comes good then we can search next text with loop command and use the same code to get building block.

Where are your building blocks saved?  And where is the code stored?  In your "Normal" template?

Normal template only.

That is my macro, which can be found in my page on AutoText, AutoCorrect and Building  Blocks. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock

Given a document reference, and an array of Building Block names, this method should replace the name of each building block with its corresponding content, for all instances found in the document:
Sub CheckAllBB()
'
' Assumes that the Building Block is of the type AutoText (wdTypeAutoText) in Category "General"
' See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243303(v=office.12).aspx
'
' This is based in part upon contributions from Greg Maxey and Jay Freedman - any errors remain mine
' Written by Charles Kenyon February 2016
'
    Dim sBBName As Variant, sTempName As String
    Dim oBB As BuildingBlock, oBBT As BuildingBlockType, doc As Document
    
    sTempName = ThisDocument.FullName
    Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks  ' thank you Timothy Rylatt
    Set oBBT = Application.Templates(sTempName).BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeAutoText)
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument 'the document with placeholders to be replaced
    
    'loop over building block names
    For Each sBBName In Array("MyBB1", "MyBB2", "MyBB3")
        Set oBB = Nothing    'reset to nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        'Try to get the building block
        Set oBB = oBBT.Categories("General").BuildingBlocks(sBBName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not oBB Is Nothing Then 'got the building block?
            ReplaceAllBB doc, oBB  'perform the replacement(s)
        Else
            MsgBox "The Building Block '" & sBBName & "' cannot be found in " & _
                    ThisDocument.Name & ".", vbExclamation, "Building Block not found"
        End If
    Next sBBName
        
End Sub


Sub ReplaceAllBB(doc As Document, BB As BuildingBlock)
    Dim allBB As New Collection, rng As Range
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Text = BB.Name
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        Do While .Execute
            allBB.Add rng.Duplicate
        Loop
    End With
    Debug.Print "Found " & allBB.Count; " instances of '" & BB.Name & "'"
    For Each rng In allBB
        BB.Insert rng, True
    Next rng
End Sub


Thanks for your reply. Saved the code in normal vba mode. After running the code, list of macro popup comingup in that unable to find the "ReplaceALLBB"  and also checked in macroIn list box  and it not shown in any group

You need to call it from your code like ReplaceAllBB ActiveDoument, oBB

'Sub ReplaceAllBB()
With activedocument.Content
Dim allBB As New Collection, rng As Range
With rng.Find
.Forward = True
.Text = BB.Name
.MatchWholeWord = True
Do While .Execute
allBB.Add rng.Duplicate
Loop
End With
Debug.Print "Found " & allBB.Count; " instances of '" & BB.Name & "'"
For Each rng In allBB
BB.Insert rng, True
Next rng
End With
End Sub'

New to macro/vba code. sorry for troubling every one. i am getting error no 91 "object variable or with block variable not set"

Please don't share code via online files - you can edit your question to add your code there, and explain the specific problem you're having.

Ok sure. Online link deleted. New code named insert table added above . I am unable to run two macro with loop cmd.

I've updated my code above to show how you can loop over an array of building block names, and replace each instance of the name in a document with the building block content.

Thanks Tim Williams, charles Kenyon for supporting me with the codes and clarification. Learned few searched few and finally full set of code came good and that fulfilled what i needed. It saved 1hr in my 9hrs working time. :)
